# How can I recursively batch convert CSS units in an entire project?

Tags: css, sass

I'm doing an experiment and would like to recursively convert pxs to rems in all the scss files in my project. There are 1248 occurrences in 60 files, so I'd rather not do it manually, or even file by file.
It would be helpful to be able to set the base size as well, but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: One option would be a regular expression that replaces matches with the new calculated values, probably.

Comment: Yes, going along with @CertainPerformance 's suggestion, you could do a find/replace with regex group matching for the digits -- something like `(\d)(\d+)px` could be replaced with `$1.$2rems`; and `(\d)px` replaced by `$1rems`